# How to add/transfer the values list from one model to another in django?

Tags: django, model, addition, transfer

Let me show you what I have done successfully and what I am trying to achieve now.

I have 2 models. Both has same 3 fields. Name, Month, Number. Two models are Main and BMO.

I filter the first model based on name and month and get the values list of the number column. Code looks like this-

```html
result= Main.objects.filter(name="John", month='apr').values_list('number', flat=True)
```

Then I display that on django template with a for loop and conditional. Code looks like this -

```html
<p>result:
    <span>
        {% for i in result %}
            {{i}}{% if not forloop.last %}+{% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

    </span>
</p>


result = 2+4+12+7+18
```

The last line showing you how it actually looks on the template. You can see I display it with + signs between the values.

What I want to achieve:

I want to get the sames values list but instead of showing it on the template I want to insert it to another model's field. Just to be clear I want all the values with plus sign included (the way it looks on my template) to be inserted in a single field of the second model BMO. If I have 10 values they should all be joined by plus sign and added in a single field, not spread into 10 rows of a column.

HERE IS WHAT I TRIED:

I filtered the second model BMO based on name and month and tried updating the number with .update() method. I added the following line of code in views.py right below the first line of code. I am not using the template at all.

```html
result= Main.objects.filter(name="John", month='apr').values_list('number', flat=True)

Bmo.objects.filter(name="test", month='apr).update(number = result)
```

It didn't change or add anything to it. So I tried a new line of code with a for loop like this -

```html
result= Main.objects.filter(name="John", month='apr').values_list('number', flat=True)

for i in result:
    Bmo.objects.filter(name__icontains = 'test').update(number = i)
```

This also didn't change a thing. There is only 1 row with name 'test' so I didn't bother with month filter. Wasn't totally convinced with the for loop but I had successfully updated categories with name match with this exact code before so thought this might work. The difference is the category was a single string like category='personal' instead of a variable or multiple variables as in this case.

I think I am very close to achieving what I want to , within a line or two codes. If there is a simpler way of doing what I am trying to do, I am all ears. Thank you for any input.

UPDATE:

After getting the answer from Ahtisham I updated the code. But it hasn't changed anything unfortunately. I am trying it within the same model. Nothing breaks. No errors in console. I run the code and nothing happens. Here is how the main part of views.py looks:

```html
def index(request):
    form = BmoForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BmoForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    R = Bmo.objects.all()

    var="apr"
    result = Bmo.objects.filter(name="Transfer", month=var).values_list('number', flat=True)
    number = str()
    count = len(products1)
    new = 12+3
    for index, r in enumerate(products1):
        number +=str(r) + '+' if count != index+1 else str(r)
    Bmo.objects.filter(name = "test", month = "apr").update(number = number)
```

The variable "new" is there for test only. When I hard code the variable to update with, it works. But it won't update with variable "number".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
result = Main.objects.filter(
   name="John", month='apr'
).values_list('number', flat=True)

number = str()
count = len(result)

for index, r in enumerate(result):
  number += str(r) + '+' if count != index + 1 else str(r)

Bmo.objects.filter(name="test", month='apr').update(number = number)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work. Thank you so much for the answer. It looked so logical and had high hopes. For some reason it is not updating and leaving the field blank. No error in console either. Nothing breaks. Just no update. It is only working if I hard code the variable I want to update with. I even tried in the same model. I will post my views.py in my main post in case anything clicks. Thanks again.

Comment: What is the type of field update question with your models.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question correctly, but in models they are all CharField if that is what you are asking.

Comment: Does this `Bmo.objects.filter(name="test", month='apr')` return more than one objects ?

Comment: No. There is only one object under the name 'test'. It has month = apr and number field is blank.

Comment: check value of `result` what does it return ?

Comment: I can see in your view you have to use `result` but you use `products1` change that and it should fix the issue.

Comment: Got it. The variable mix up was not an issue in the main code, that was a change I tried to make here to make it more readable. But you pointed me to the right direction. When I did the initial filter for result the name Transfer had nothing for month apr. It is fixed now and working like a charm. You are a legend Ahtisham. Thank you so much.